# CUDA shared memory - sum reduction from kernel

Tags: cuda

I am working on big datasets that are image cubes (450x450x1500). I have a kernel that works on individual data elements. Each data element produces 6 intermediate results (floats). My block consists of 1024 threads. The 6 intermediate results are stored in shared memory by each thread (6 float arrays). However, now I need to add each of the intermediate result to produce a sum (6 sum values). I do not have enough global memory to save these 6 float arrays to global memory and then run a reduction from thrust or any other library from the host code.

Are there any reduction routines that can be called from inside a kernel function on arrays in shared memory?

What will be the best way to solve this problem? I am a newbie to CUDA programming and would welcome any suggestions.

Comment: By '6 sum values', do you mean your final result only contains 6 floats or you will do reduction on only 6 floats for 450x450x1500 times?

Comment: The final result contains 6 floats. The sum is over the third dimension (1500). So I finally need to end up with 450x450x6 floats.

Comment: So how is your image cube stored in global mem? Frame after frame like `image[1500][450][450]` or pixel after pixel like `image[450][450][1500]`

Comment: It is first along the z then along x and y. So image[1500][450][450]. I have a thread processing each voxel. Since a block cannot have 1500 threads, I am using 512 threads per block and splitting the 1500 into three blocks. I will need to eventually accumulate results from all three blocks. I am thinking that I will use temporary global memory (450x450x6) to save the intermediate sum values from each block. Is that a good way to do this?

Comment: You don't need to sum one 1500-D vector using multiple blocks or multiple theads. Using one thread is enough for your case. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

This seems unlikely:

> I do not have enough global memory to save these 6 float arrays to global memory and then run a reduction from thrust or any other library from the host code.

I can't imagine how you have enough space to store your data in shared memory but not in global memory.

Anyway, [CUB](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/) provides reduction routines that can be called from within a threadblock, and that can operate on data stored in shared memory.

Or you can write your own sum-reduction code.  It's not terribly hard to do, there are many questions on SO about it, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101539/cuda-reduction-basics).

Or you could adapt the [cuda sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction).

Comment: The problem is that I already have large volumes allocated on the device. I am using K4000 with 3 GB memory. The floats that need to be added up are calculated for each of the voxels. For example (a smaller volume that in my earlier question), if my volume size is 300x300x1500, I would need 300x300x1500x6x4  = ~ 3.01 GB if I have to save the intermediate values to global memory. My understanding was that since the processing is not all scheduled at once, shared memory is able to hold this as only parts of the data need to be in the real memory at any time.

Comment: Yes, then it probably makes sense to keep the sums as you're processing the data.  Any of the 3 approaches I mentioned could be used in that fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I implemented the parallel reduction based on the explanation by Mark Harris. But however now I have a new problem. As mentioned in my comments in reply to Eric, I have to reduce 1500 elements. But due to the maximum limit to the block, I am splitting the data into 3 segments of 512 each. I have the 3(3x6) results from each of the blocks. I am writing the result from the blocks to global memory and accumulating. But am getting different results each time because the order of execution of the blocks is not constant. Can I synchronize across blocks?

Comment: There is no built-in method to synchronize across blocks.  The same problem arises in the standard reduction example, so if you study that, you will find approaches to dealing with this.  You could use an [atomic](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) function to handle the writes/updates to global memory (it sounds like each block is writing just a few values, so this should not be a huge performance issue) or extend the classical parallel reduction to a multi-kernel approach.  There are other possibilities as well.  Maybe pose a new SO question.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

After seeing all the comments, I understand that instead of doing 1 or a few times of reduction, you need to do the reductions for 450x450x6 times.

In this case there's simpler solution.

You don't need to implement relatively complex parallel reduction for each 1500-D vector。 Since you already have 450x450x6 vectors to reduce, you could reduce all these vectors in parallel using traditional serial reduction method.

You could use a block with 16x16 threads to process a particular region of the image, and a grid with 29x29 blocks to cover the whole 450x450 image.

In each thread, you could iterate over the 1500 frames. In each iterration, you coulde first compute the 6 intermediate results, then add them to the sums. When yo finish all the iterations, you could write the 6 sums to global mem.

That finishes the kernel design. And no shared mem is needed.

You wil find that the performance is very good. Since it is a memory bound operation,it won't be much longer than simply access all the image cube data once.

In case you don't have enough global mem for the whole cube, you could split it into 4 sub-cubes of [1500][225][225], and call the kernel routine on each sub-cube. The only thing you need to change is the grid size.

Comment: Hi Eric, I do not have the 450x450x1500x6 values to start with.  The values that I have to sum have to be first computed from each of the voxels. Also since the data sizes are large, I cannot even save the 450x450x1500x6 (floats) to global memory to do processing later.

Comment: Hi Eric, since intermediate values have to be computed from each pixel, using only 450x450 threads seems to be not optimal. In this case, each thread has to read in the 1500 values from global memory and then do the same computation on each of the pixels. Isnt this best parallelized?

Comment: @user2789280 my approach don't store 450x450x1500x6 floats to global mem. the intermediate results will be added to sum right after they are computed out. 450x450 threads i.e. 29*29 blocks of 256-thread-block can fulfill all the SMs of GPU. In fact for CC2.0 devices, only 32 such blocks are able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) that explains parallel reduction in CUDA thoroughly.

Comment: This is an older version of the doc that is available at my cuda sample code link.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, each thread should sum up "only" `6` floats.

I'm not sure if it is worth doing that by a parallel reduction in general, in the sense that you will experience performance gains.

If you are targeting a Kepler, you may try to use *shuffle* operations if you properly set the block size so that your intermediate results fit the Streaming Multiprocessor's registers in some way.

As also pointed out by Robert Crovella, your statement about the possibility of storing the intermediate results seems strange as the amount of global memory is certainly larger than the amount of shared memory.

Comment: Please see my comments to the previous two replies. The reduction is over 1500 elements and the space is limited because of the big data size.